# EF Update is not Updating the GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, gridview, mvvm

I'm still in the learning Phase of WPF, EF and MVVM and now I got the following problem. I can delete and insert new items in my DataGridView but I don't know how to update my items.

All I do is select an emptyrow which already has a primary key and then I put the data into it. It's working (updating database) but the GridView is not refreshing. I Need to restart the program first to see my updated data.

My Execute Command to Update my Database. I'm in the ViewModel class

```
        public void ExecuteUpdate(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                
                SelectedIndex.Child_Update(new Farbe { FarbauswahlNr = SelectedIndex.FarbauswahlNr, Kurztext = SelectedIndex.Kurztext, Ressource = SelectedIndex.Ressource, Vari1 = SelectedIndex.Vari1, Vari2 = SelectedIndex.Vari2 });
                //ListeAktualisieren --> Refreshing the List
                ListeAktualisieren();                     
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());   
            }
        }
```

Here is my Refresh Method which SHOULD Refresh the GridView. I'm in the ViewModel class

```
        public void ListeAktualisieren()
        {


            farbliste.ListeAktualisieren(db);
            farbliste.Model = farbliste.Model.Concat(farbliste.Addlist).ToList();
            Model = farbliste.Model;
            farbliste.Addlist.Clear();
        }
```

The method is calling my Business List which also got a Refresh Method. Reading from my database here. I'm in the Business List class

```
    public void ListeAktualisieren(TestDBEntities db)
    {
        Model.Clear();
        foreach (var item in db.Farben)
        {
            //Insert and delete working
            add = new Farbe { FarbauswahlNr = item.FarbauswahlNr, Kurztext = item.Kurztext, Ressource = item.Ressource, Vari1 = Convert.ToBoolean(item.Var1), Vari2 = item.Vari2 };
            Addlist.Add(add);              
        }           

    }
```

Model is the Source of my GridView which is not Refreshing changed data when Updated but is showing new data rows when inserting or deleting.

Answer (score 2):

You need Observablecollections and Classes with implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. Add the new element to the Observablecollection by insert and raise the event propertychanged by a change.
The rest should be done by WPF.

Edit: The Sourcecollection for the DataGrid needs to be the Observablecollection.

---

Edit2: To be nice I put the result of the comments here ;-)
Each row of the DataGrid is an element of the collection. Each cell of one row listens to a PropertyChangedEvent of its element (the String is Casesensitive so be carefull). If the getter of the property isn't called after the propertychangedevent the binding didn't receive the event. 
This piece of Code can help asure that you don't call with nonexistent strings:

```
private void VerifyPropertyName(string PropertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName))
        return;
    if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)(PropertyName) == null) {
        string msg = "Ungültiger PropertyName: " + PropertyName;
        if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName) {
            throw new isgException(msg);
        } else {
            Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i do have a OnPropertyChange in my property.

Comment: the PropertyChangedEvent has to reach the WPF-Layer how is your connection from ViewModel to WPF?

Comment: Farbliste.cs and Farbe.cs are CSLA classen so i dont think there is an an Observablecollection  needed?

Comment: You are right I did't read your code carefully enought :-). Do you Notify Propertychanged with the correct string? (Casesensitive)

Comment: yes. FarbViewModel got the Property Model. But it is getting it from FarbListe.cs

Comment: I don't use telerik myself but is  IsReadOnly="True" right? because you are not using the datagrid readonly if understand you right.

Comment: I think the problmen could be that Model is not gettin a new value like in Delete and insert, and thats why it's not changing the GridView. But i dont know how to handle this Problem either :D

Comment: Yeah im using Textboxes to edit the rows and not the gridView. So ISReadOnly doesnt effect my Handlings ist just turning of the cells in the GridView.

Comment: Bruteforce solution would be dataGrid.Items.Refresh() but that would reload the whole datagrid => not good with much data the problem is your PropertyChanged Event doesn't reach the DataGrid. You could try to debug why it doesn't get that far.

Comment: Well but Insert and Delete are working so it doese reach the DataGrid right? 
and dataGrid.Itenms.Refresh() isnt possible because u mean to wirte it in the FarbeView.xaml.cs right? 
Im working after the MVVM-Model and thats why my FarbeView.xaml.cs are nearly empty.

Comment: there would be other ways but I wouldn't recommend them. The **Collection**ChangedEvent reaches the DataGrid not the **Property**ChangedEvent. I don't know all your classes or telerik but usually a you have a binding in the datagridcell and when the PropertyChangedEvent is raised, the Property gets reavalueted. and this doesn't happen, does it?

Comment: not sure what u mean :D but have a look at my propertyChange Method

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the getter of the Property you are changing and you will hit it if the Property gets reavaluated after the change (Propertychangedevent has been received by the other participant of the binding). if it doesn't get hit you have to find out where the chain of events stopps. For your understanding: each row is an element of your collection and each cell is listening to the propertychangedevent of that element with a certain string. it updates when the event comes with the right string. Since I don't have your infrastructure or telerik I can only wish you "Good Hunting".

Comment: aww maaaan :D i appreciate ur help^^

Comment: intresting... i found a way how update is working. but then delete and insert not working right. and when delete and insert r working properly the update isnt working :D
Lets go back to Assembler >_>

Comment: well i think the solution is clear. I'll start the Project from new :D 
my csla List class is pretty messed up and not like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your binding section
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged"}